# .equals(null) is probably not what was intended

Tags: android, null, calculator

I am trying to make a Calculator Application and i have a problem :
the `(null)` is colored in orange and it says: .equals(null) is probably not what was intended.What should i do?

```
case R.id.equal: if(!optr.equals(null)){
                    if(op2 != 0){
                        if(optr.equals("+")){
                            disp.setText(""); /*op1 = op1 + op2;*/
                         disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
```

Comment: How about https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: What exactly do you want to check `optr` against? `null`, empty String (""), blank Strings, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how you do it. Null is not an object - so has no equals:

```
case R.id.equal: if(optr!=null){
                    if(op2 != 0){
                        if(optr.equals("+")){
                            disp.setText(""); /*op1 = op1 + op2;*/
                         disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to check if `optr` is either `null` or the empty String. In this case, use `TextUtils.isEmpty()`:

```
case R.id.equal: if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(optr)){
                    if(op2 != 0){
                        if(optr.equals("+")){
                            disp.setText(""); /*op1 = op1 + op2;*/
                         disp.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(op1));
```